# Passing parameters via URL displays it as [object object] instead of string (typescript)

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, http

HI I am trying to pass through some string parameters to my url so that I can get information from the API.

This works fine and when shown in a alert displays the url exactly as it should be (does not contain [object, object]).

```
var startDate = "2020-09-20" ;
var endDate = "2020-11-20";
var apiUrl = 'https://thisismyurls7F174D955BF8&dateFrom='+{startDate}+' &dateTo='+{endDate}+'T18%3A56%3A58.930Z&showAllFutureItinerary=true'
```

However when I do this.

```
CustomSearch(startDate: string,endDate: string)
  {
   var Url = 'https://localhost:44381/api/internal/itinerary/all?userId=996D7BD5-C625-5C7E-6A02- 7F174D955BF8&dateFrom='+{startDate}+'T18%3A56%3A58.930Z&dateTo='+ {endDate}+'T18%3A56%3A58.930Z&showAllFutureItinerary=true'.toString();

}
```

It cannot access the API and when console.logged/alerted shows the variables are both as [object object].

These are passed from a onsubmit function from another component as shown below.

```js
model = {
  startDate: String,
  endDate: String,
  search: String
}

constructor(private itineraryService: ItineraryService) {}

onSubmit() {
    // var a = JSON.stringify(this.model)

    if (this.model.endDate != undefined && this.model.startDate != undefined) {
      this.items = this.itineraryService.CustomSearch(this.model.startDate.toString(), this.model.endDate.toString())
    }
```

I basically just need to make these both as strings instead of them appearing as [object object]

Comment: Writing `"url" + {startDate}` is equilvalent to `"url" + { startDate: startDate }`. You can creating an object instead of doing string interpolation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not using template literals correctly. `{ startDate }` creates an object literal using [Shorthand property names](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer#New_notations_in_ECMAScript_2015). When you concatenate an object with a string , it calls the `toString` method on the object and becomes `[object, Object]`

```js
const start = 'abc',
      obj = { start }

console.log(obj)

console.log(
  'some string' + { start }
)
```

- [Template literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals) should be wrapped in back ticks, not quotes
- The expressions should be wrapped in `${ expression }` with a `$`

Change it to:

```
var apiUrl = `https://thisismyurls7F174D955BF8&dateFrom=${startDate}&dateTo=${endDate}T18%3A56%3A58.930Z&showAllFutureItinerary=true`
```

Comment: Hi Adiga thankyou !! You are absoultely correct sorry if this was a dumb question!

Comment: @henrypeters it's not dumb at all. `{ startDate }` creating an object is not very easy to identify. Always check the documentation on MDN when you're unsure about the syntax.